# Is DNS a directory service or directory lookup service?

Tags: networking, dns, terminology

I really confuse these two terms, I've seen that DNS is **NOT a directory service** But while I was reading about it in some textbook it mentioned that DNS is a **"Directory lookup service"**

Can anyone explain the difference between both terms and if they're the same, which one is the correct description?

Comment: A simple question which requires a long answer :)

Comment: That textbook was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is DNS?

There are three acronyms that correspond to DNS. They tend to be used interchangeably but in fact have different meanings.

1. **D**omain **N**ame **S**ystem.
2. **D**omain **N**ame **S**erver.
3. **D**omain **N**ame **S**ervice.

---

#### Domain Name System

The Domain Name System provides a **worldwide distributed Directory Service**.

It does this using a network of **Domain Name Servers**.

> The Domain Name System (DNS) is a hierarchical decentralized naming system for computers, services, or any resource connected to the Internet or a private network. It associates various information with domain names assigned to each of the participating entities. Most prominently, it translates more readily memorized domain names to the numerical IP addresses needed for the purpose of locating and identifying computer services and devices with the underlying network protocols. By providing a worldwide, distributed directory service, the Domain Name System is an essential component of the functionality of the Internet, and has been in use since the 1980s.
>
> The Domain Name System delegates the responsibility of assigning domain names and mapping those names to Internet resources by designating authoritative name servers for each domain. Network administrators may delegate authority over sub-domains of their allocated name space to other name servers. This mechanism provides distributed and fault tolerant service and was designed to avoid a single large central database.

Source [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)

---

#### Domain Name Server

This is a server Running a **Domain Name Service**. The server may be running all kinds of other services as well.

The service that a Domain Name Server provides can be thought of as a **Directory Lookup Service** as they maintain a Directory of Domain Names.

Given a name the Domain Name Server is able to return the IP address corresponding to the name (assuming there is a matching entry in the Directory).

> Domain Name Servers (DNS) are the Internet's equivalent of a phone
>   book. They maintain a directory of domain names and translate them to
>   Internet Protocol (IP) addresses.
>
> This is necessary because, although domain names are easy for people
>   to remember, computers or machines, access websites based on IP
>   addresses.
>
> Information from all the domain name servers across the Internet are
>   gathered together and housed at the Central Registry. Host companies
>   and Internet Service Providers interact with the Central Registry on a
>   regular schedule to get updated DNS information.
>
> When you type in a web address, e.g., www.jimsbikes.com, your Internet
>   Service Provider views the DNS associated with the domain name,
>   translates it into a machine friendly IP address (for example
>   216.168.224.70 is the IP for jimsbikes.com) and directs your Internet connection to the correct website.
>
> After you register a new domain name or when you update the DNS
>   servers on your domain name, it usually takes about 12-36 hours for
>   the domain name servers world-wide to be updated and able to access
>   the information. This 36-hour period is referred to as propagation.

Source [What Is A Domain Name Server (DNS) And How Does It Work](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/what-is-a-domain-name-server-dns-and-how-does-it-work/)

---

#### Domain Name Service

The Domain Name Service is a service running on port 53 on a **Domain Name Server**.

This port is where a request is sent to in order to resolve a name to an IP address.

> During DNS resolution, DNS messages are sent from DNS clients to DNS servers or between DNS servers. Messages are sent over UDP and DNS servers bind to UDP port 53. When the message length exceeds the default message size for a User Datagram Protocol (UDP) datagram (512 octets), the first response to the message is sent with as much data as the UDP datagram will allow, and then the DNS server sets a flag indicating a truncated response. The message sender can then choose to reissue the request to the DNS server using TCP (over TCP port 53). The benefit of this approach is that it takes advantage of the performance of UDP but also has a backup failover solution for longer queries.
>
> In general, all DNS queries are sent from a high-numbered source port (49152 or above) to destination port 53, and responses are sent from source port 53 to a high-numbered destination port.

Source [Network Ports Used by DNS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197515%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)